# Why ios/build folder is not included to .gitignore file?

Tags: ios, git, flutter, gitignore

Why ios/build is not included to gitignore by default?

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        ios/build/
```

`/.gitignore` file

```
# Miscellaneous
*.class
*.log
*.pyc
*.swp
.DS_Store
.atom/
.buildlog/
.history
.svn/

# IntelliJ related
*.iml
*.ipr
*.iws
.idea/

# The .vscode folder contains launch configuration and tasks you configure in
# VS Code which you may wish to be included in version control, so this line
# is commented out by default.
#.vscode/

# Flutter/Dart/Pub related
**/doc/api/
**/ios/Flutter/.last_build_id
.dart_tool/
.flutter-plugins
.flutter-plugins-dependencies
.packages
.pub-cache/
.pub/
/build/

# Web related
lib/generated_plugin_registrant.dart

# Symbolication related
app.*.symbols

# Obfuscation related
app.*.map.json

# Android Studio will place build artifacts here
/android/app/debug
/android/app/profile
/android/app/release

/lib/credentials.dart
```

`/ios/.gitignore` file:

```
*.mode1v3
*.mode2v3
*.moved-aside
*.pbxuser
*.perspectivev3
**/*sync/
.sconsign.dblite
.tags*
**/.vagrant/
**/DerivedData/
Icon?
**/Pods/
**/.symlinks/
profile
xcuserdata
**/.generated/
Flutter/App.framework
Flutter/Flutter.framework
Flutter/Flutter.podspec
Flutter/Generated.xcconfig
Flutter/app.flx
Flutter/app.zip
Flutter/flutter_assets/
Flutter/flutter_export_environment.sh
ServiceDefinitions.json
Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.*

# Exceptions to above rules.
!default.mode1v3
!default.mode2v3
!default.pbxuser
!default.perspectivev3
```

Comment: coz `/build/` means the `build` folder in current dir. you could change it to `build/` to ignore all folders named as build

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in [`gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

> If there is a separator at the beginning or middle (or both) of the pattern, then the pattern is relative to the directory level of the particular `.gitignore` file itself.
>
> Otherwise the pattern may also match at any level below the .gitignore level.

Once you have changed the pattern to build/, don't forget you also have, to validate if that works:

```
git check-ignore -v -- ios/build/aFile
```

That should print the `.gitignore` rule line, which does ignore the folder.